# React Native FlatList blocks InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

### PROBLEM

I have a FlatList that renders multiple items (+100 images). When it is rendering items the interaction with my tab navigator is broken, I mean, I can't press any button until all items are rendered. Also, when I try to run InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions nothing happens.

All works perfect if I delete the FlatList so I think there is somthing wrong with my FlatList implementation that brokes the app, but I don't know what... I have been reading the documentation an all props I pass to the FlatList have the main purpose of a smoothly interaction without blank areas.

How can I fix this issue?

### CODE WHERE I USE INTERACTION MANAGER

```
  const handleConfirm = () => {
    if (!isCropping) {
      setIsCropping(true);
      cropPhoto().then((croppedPhoto) => {
        navigation.navigate("PostCreator", {
          photo: croppedPhoto,
        });
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
          console.log("This code doesn't run when the FlatList is rendering... :C");
          setIsCropping(false);
        });
      });
    }
  };
```

### CODE OF FLATLIST

```
 <FlatList
      data={data}
      legacyImplementation={false}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
      initialNumToRender={7}
      windowSize={21}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={75}
      updateCellsBatchingPeriod={150}
      removeClippedSubviews
      ListFooterComponent={
        isLoading ? (
          <View style={styles.footer}>
            <Loading type="ios" size={20} color={colors.gray} />
          </View>
        ) : null
      }
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Image component from "react-native-elements". I just moved to the original from the react-native library and all works fine.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Any other suggestion?